# Trouble installing RMySQL on Windows 8

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I followed the installation directions at [R-Bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-the-rmysql-package-on-windows-7/) website. However once I do the `install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')`, I get the following error. It appears that there is some conflict with regards to the path (Windows likes backward slashes whereas here the installer is trying to look up by unix style backward slashes). Any ideas what is going wrong?

--- Error Message ---
    install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')

Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Software/R-2.15.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz'

Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 165363 bytes (161 Kb)

opened URL

downloaded 161 Kb

- installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ...

** package 'RMySQL' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

checking for $MYSQL_HOME... C:\Software\xampp\mysql

cygwin warning:

**MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Software\xampp\mysql**

Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Software/xampp/mysql

CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.

Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:

```
http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
```

** libs
Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,

so building only the main architecture

cygwin warning:

**MS-DOS style path detected: C:/Software/R-215~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf**

Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Software/R-215~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf

CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.

Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:

```
http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
```

gcc -m64 -I"C:/Software/R-215~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:\Software\xampp\mysql"/include    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c

RS-DBI.c -o RS-DBI.o

RS-DBI.c: In function 'RS_na_set':

RS-DBI.c:1219:11: warning: variable 'c' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

gcc -m64 -I"C:/Software/R-215~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:\Software\xampp\mysql"/include    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c

RS-MySQL.c -o RS-MySQL.o

RS-MySQL.c: In function 'RS_MySQL_fetch':

RS-MySQL.c:657:13: warning: variable 'fld_nullOk' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

RS-MySQL.c: In function 'RS_DBI_invokeBeginGroup':

RS-MySQL.c:1137:30: warning: variable 'val' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

RS-MySQL.c: In function 'RS_DBI_invokeNewRecord':

RS-MySQL.c:1158:20: warning: variable 'val' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

RS-MySQL.c: In function 'RS_MySQL_dbApply':

RS-MySQL.c:1219:38: warning: variable 'fld_nullOk' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RMySQL.dll tmp.def RS-DBI.o RS-MySQL.o

C:\Software\xampp\mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/Software/R-215~1.2/bin/x64 -lR

gcc.exe: error: C:\Software\xampp\mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll: No such file or directory

ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'

- removing 'C:/Software/R-2.15.2/library/RMySQL'

Warning in install.packages :
  running command 'C:/Software/R-215~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD INSTALL -l "C:/Software/R-2.15.2/library"

**C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiIQAUp/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz' had status 1**

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiIQAUp\downloaded_packages’

Comment: Ignore the warnings. The important part is the error.  Find the dll its looking for and copy it to the directory that it thinks it should be in.

Comment: After copying the dll and running the command, I get the following error:  `C:\Software\xampp\mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/Software/R-215~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
collect2: ld returned 5 exit status
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'`

Comment: Its a link error so maybe it can't find a library?  See if there are any libraries there and copy them to the same directory too.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy all the files and folders from inside lib to the bin folder.

For some strange reason the installer looks for the lib files in the bin directory.